# Trouble with creating a grouped Boxplot in R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, boxplot

I am trying to create a grouped Boxplot in R Studio with ggplot2.

My Data looks like this:

[image: Data Set]

(4 different APP.mm values in total)

And a sample `dput()` of my dataset:

```
structure(list(APP.mm = c(408.5, 408.5, 408.5, 408.5, 408.5, 
408.5, 408.5, 408.5, 408.5, 408.5, 408.5, 237.5, 237.5, 237.5, 
237.5, 237.5, 237.5, 237.5, 237.5, 237.5, 237.5, 237.5, 237.5, 
237.5, 237.5, 132.1, 132.1, 132.1, 132.1, 132.1, 132.1, 132.1, 
274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274), Weight_mg = c(112, 
106.72, 118.4, 62.3, 86.2, 70.3, 56.5, 71, 61.4, 61.7, 62.7, 
81.1, 125.5, 71, 120.4, 75.3, 68.1, 95.9, 77.5, 95.5, 85.3, 64.1, 
27.6, 20.5, 77.9, 86.3, 120, 100.2, 86.4, 67.8, 104.4, 90.1, 
71.1, 89, 77.4, 77.1, 60.5, 78.7, 87.9, 71.1, 76.5), Germination = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("APP.mm", "Weight_mg", 
"Germination"), row.names = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 
91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 2111L, 2112L, 2113L, 2114L, 2115L, 2116L, 
2117L, 2118L, 2119L, 2120L, 2121L, 2122L, 2123L, 2124L, 2674L, 
2675L, 2676L, 2677L, 2678L, 2679L, 2680L, 3193L, 3194L, 3195L, 
3196L, 3197L, 3198L, 3199L, 3200L, 3201L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am now trying to create a Grouped Boxplot with the APP.mm on the x-Axis, the Weight on the Y-Axis and the values grouped by APP.mm into Germination Succes (1) oder No Germination Success (0)

I tried these codes for R:

```
ggplot(data = gallsdtg, aes(x=APP.mm, y=Weight_mg)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Germination))

Warning message:
Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)? 


ggplot(data = gallsdtg, aes(x=APP.mm, y=Weight_mg)) +
 geom_boxplot(aes(group=Germination))

qplot(gallsdtg$APP.mm, gallsdtg$Weight_mg,
 fill=factor(galls$Germination), geom="boxplot")
```

resulting in this plot:
[image: Plot 1]

I tried the exact same code on the same structure of Data just from a different location and got the plot I wanted.

```
qplot(germination2017extras$APP.mm, germination2017extras$Weight_mg, 
  fill=factor(germination2017extras$Germination), geom="boxplot", 
  xlab="mean APP in mm", ylab="Weight in mg", ylim=c(0,200))
```

[image: Plot 2]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please dput() part of your data set?

Comment: I added it to the top post (Hope I did it right, sorry my first time here....)

Comment: ggplot2 will produce the correct plot with this code: `ggplot(data = df, aes(x=as.factor(APP.mm), y=Weight_mg, fill = as.factor(Germination))) +
  geom_boxplot()`

Comment: @LAP thank you so much!